# C# Library for consuming Geoserver REST?

Tags: geoserver, c#

I am currently experimenting with Geoserver and it's capabilities within C#. One thing I would like to do is query the server for basic information (existing workspaces, layers, layer attributes, etc...)

I noticed that Geoserver does have a [REST implementation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-api.html), but is there a C# implementation for consuming this service?

I am sure a library could easily be written, but I would hate to re-invent the wheel if one already exists.

---

This can be done using C# WebRequests. However, what I would have created is a C# library for consuming the Geoserver REST implementation. It seems like something many people would use.

Does a library full of C# WebRequests exist to consume Geoserver's REST implementation?"

It is much easier if a library already exists with classes such as these to consume the webservice, than it is to create an entire library. For Example:

```
var geoserver = new Geoserver("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web");
var workSpaces = geoserver.Workspaces;
var layer = geoserver.Workspaces[0].Layers["Foo"];
```

The above code is the type of implementation I would really enjoy. If I was to create a library that consumed the Geoserver REST service. The above is what I would create for myself to use. If it wasn't created already, I would likely make an opensource project that others could use as well. So that in the future, if someone is wanting a library to easily consume the Geoserver service, they can contribute and use the one that already exists!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested the library, but the [GSRCC library](https://code.google.com/p/gsrcc/) looks promising place to start: https://code.google.com/p/gsrcc/

> The [GSRCC library](https://code.google.com/p/gsrcc/) is a C#.net Client to the Geoserver 2.1.x+ RESTful configuration
>   extension. Using this library, one can access a remote Geoserver via
>   HTTP and configure it.
>
> The REST extension of Geoserver has to be installed on Geoserver.
>
> This project uses .net framework 4.0 and has no extra dependencies!
>
> This is a conversion from the http://code.google.com/p/gsrcj/, which
>   is a Java Api. Since there was no C# .net API for accessing the REST
>   Api for Geoserver.
>
> The first version aims to implement the same thing in the java
>   version, and latter to implement the full rest api.

Answer (score 2):

I use [RESTSHARP](http://restsharp.org/) for communicating with many REST web services. Makes everything a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a perfectly reasonable question to ask, no-one wants to reinvent the wheel. I had a similar requirement on a project and I too could not find a C# assembly that would make working with GeoServer easier.

In the end I created a class within my project to simplify the REST calls to/from GeoServer but it was specifically tuned to my needs. I would happily contribute to an Open Source project to create a C# management assembly for GeoServer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for such a solution and somehow stumbles upon this post. Here is a working solution:

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp_Free_Code/API/Download_Geoserver_Rest_Net.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use also this .NET GeoServer implementation library: https://github.com/sibies/GeoServer.Net